# max in sql don't get the correct results from database(using laravel framework)

Tags: sql, laravel

I using the laravel framework and i am trying to get the max date for each address and display it.But it doesn't work as i expected,with max it doesn't bring me back the correct row.

```
$locations = \DB::table('mesaurement')
->select(\DB::raw('mesaurement.ID as ID,mesaurement.Latitude,mesaurement.Longitute,mesaurement.Temperature as temp,mesaurement.Humidity,mesaurement.Pressure,mesaurement.address, mesaurement.created_at,max(created_at) as date'))
->orderby('date','desc')
->groupby('mesaurement.address')
->get();
```

I wanted with the max date to bring me back the right Temperature,Humidity etc. I grouped by address because i have a lot of the same addresses and i want them to be just one.

Comment: *I grouped by address* - Where's the groupBy? Is this your actual query?

Comment: i am sorry i erased it by mistake!

Comment: Even then, not sure how this query is even working? You can't group by the address and then selecting other fields that are not part of your `groupBy`. What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: I think I understood what you probably want. Do you want to fetch the record with the highest temperature grouped by its address?

Answer (score 0):

i am unaware of the framework but the query can be simple as below

select max(temp) from mesaurement
group by mesaurement.address;

more details with multiple columns in max can be found at below link

[Multiple max values in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673802/multiple-max-values-in-a-query)